# How to redefine a variable

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm trying to get my IP and create a variable to hold that.

```
ipAddr = "F"

def ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ipAddr = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()

ip()
print(ipAddr)
#Returns F
```

When I print ipAddr after I run ip() I'd like it to return my ip.
I know the code in ip() works, when I print ipAddr in the def block it prints my ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify global variables in a function without using the `global` keyword, so add it in:

```
ipAddr = "F"

def ip():
    global ipAddr
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ipAddr = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()

ip()
print(ipAddr)
```

However, this is generally bad practice. Better to do this:

```
ipAddr = "F"

def ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ipAddr = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    return ipAddr

ipAddr = ip()
print(ipAddr)
```

Comment: What about the first one makes it bad practice?

Comment: It's just bad practice to use global variables in basically any language. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: @AustinPalmer If this answered your question, be sure to mark it as accepted for future viewers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use a `return` statement.

```
ipAddr = "F"

def ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ipAddr = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    return ipAddr

# You can assign the return value to any variable name:
# ipAddr here and ipAddr in the function are different variables
ipAddr = ip()
print(ipAddr)
```